# How to name Objects by values by an element in R?

Tags: r

I want to name a new Object dynamically to an element of an esisting object.

for example:

old object:

```
df1 <- data.frame(R = c('2','2','2','2'), P = c('e','ss','ww','tt')
```

the new objects name should be `af2`, while the `'2'` from `'af2'` should be transfered from `df1$R` or let´s say `df1[1]`.

To missunderstandings for fully clearness:

If

df1$R = c('5','5','5')

the new objects name should be `af5`

Thank you so much

Comment: what should be output if `df1$R = c('5','2','7')` ?

Comment: If you want to do this, don't put these objects into the global environment. Put them into a list.

Comment: @Saurabh13, in may case the elements of df1$R will be always equal, but to answer your question it should be 'af5'

Comment: Means first element. Right?

Comment: yes, your are right

Comment: @rimberd- Go through my solution. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Kindly go through the following solution:

```
df1 <- data.frame(R = c('2','2','2','2'), P = c('e','ss','ww','tt'))
```

Now, fetch column with name `R` and combine with `af` using `paste` function as shown below:

```
paste("af",df1$R[1],sep ="")
[1] "af2"
```

Comment: In specific i need it that way: when i definate the new object (here af2) my Code would look like:   af2 <- <expression X>     And the idea should be that in here i wouldnt need to definate 'af2' manually. I want that my object (at the beginning of the line will be named automatically such as: af(paste(df1$R[1])  <- <expression>

Comment: @rimberd- That is fine. What kind of expression you want on RHS side?